# Grid View Image Error

Tags: android, gridview

hello i am new on android. Please help.

My SingleViewActivity java

```
package com.example.helloworld;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class SingleViewActivity extends Activity
{
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
  setContentView(R.layout.single_view);

  // Get intent 
  Intent i = getIntent();

  // Selected image id
  int position = i.getExtras().getInt("id");
  ImageAdapter imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(this);

  ImageView imageView =(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.SingleView);   
  imageView.setImageResource(imageAdapter.mThumbIds[position]);}}
```

This singleview xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<ImageViewandroid:id="@+id/SingleView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

So my problem is, when thumb image clicked is not show full image

Sorry my bad english

Comment: Did you get any exception or not?

Answer (score 0):

add scale type to ImageView like this,

```
android:scaleType="fitXY"
```

Comment: How can you say that only because of use this image will be displayed. It might be other problem and solution also.